# How to exclude data with 0 variance in matlab implementation of Linear discriminant analysis

Tags: matlab, multilabel-classification, linear-discriminant

I am using Matlab to classify data using LDA.

```
  mdl = fitcdiscr(dbimgs1,indx,'DiscrimType','linear');
  C=predict(mdl,testimgs1);
```

I get the following error:

> Predictor x741 has zero variance. Either exclude this predictor or set 'discrimType' to 'pseudoLinear' or 'diagLinear'.

I do not wish to use 'pseudoLinear' or 'diagLinear' as it degrades the performance. How can I exclude the zero predictor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  delete_id=[];
  for id_var_chk=1:size(dbimgs1,2)
      if(var(dbimgs1(:,id_var_chk))<1)
             delete_id=[delete_id,id_var_chk]
      end
  end
```

The loop checks the variance of each column. The values with low variance are then deleted by:

```
 dbimgs1(:,delete_id_1(i))=[];
```